# Entity Framework 4: PropertyChanged event is raised too often

Tags: entity-framework-4, inotifypropertychanged

the generated code from EF for a property of an entity looks like this:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return _DateCreated;
            }
            set
            {
                OnDateCreatedChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("DateCreated");
                _DateCreated = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("DateCreated");
                OnDateCreatedChanged();
            }
        }
        private global::System.DateTime _DateCreated;
        partial void OnDateCreatedChanging(global::System.DateTime value);
        partial void OnDateCreatedChanged();
```

This code doesn't check if the value has actually changed (in the setter). Therefore the PropertyChanged event is raised even if you set a value that is equal to the current value. But in this case nothing would have changed, so I wouldn't want this event...

For EntityKey properties they do check this:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// No Metadata Documentation available.
        /// </summary>
        [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
        [DataMemberAttribute()]
        public global::System.Guid Id
        {
            get
            {
                return _Id;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Id != value)
                {
                    OnIdChanging(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                    ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                    OnIdChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        private global::System.Guid _Id;
        partial void OnIdChanging(global::System.Guid value);
        partial void OnIdChanged();
```

I would expect this behavior from all properties.
Am I missing a setting in the model designer, or is there another solution?

Thanx!

Comment: And I know that I could customize the T4 template for that... But I would rather not use a custom template in my project!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is point of T4 templates to allow you modifications you need. It is absolutely wrong approach to say:

> But I would rather not use a custom template in my project!

It is like throwing all advantages of T4 templates away and going back to hardcoded custom tools for code generating.

Comment: That is a valid point. But I have reasons to be reluctant to that. Introducing the possibility to modify the generated code, would make my co-developers want to make even more changes that would break any good design. As of now I can tell them: "That's the way it is!". And for most parts it is good the way it is. As you can see, there are sometimes other than technical reasons for decisions.

Comment: Developer is meant to develop and do changes he believes are good. It is not a slave - he has a responsibility for changes he did and he must be able to explain why he made them. If you don't trust your co-developers you need code review process.

Comment: Let me say that I do relay appreciate your expertise and quick help on my last few questions regarding EF !! :)

Answer (score 1):

I did, as I knew it was possible and Ladislav also stated, include the T4 template file into the project and made the following changes to the "Write PrimitiveType Properties." part of the template:

```
            if (!Object.Equals(<#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#>, value))
            {
                <#=ChangingMethodName(primitiveProperty)#>(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("<#=primitiveProperty.Name#>");
                <#=code.FieldName(primitiveProperty)#> = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value<#=OptionalNullableParameterForSetValidValue(primitiveProperty, code)#>);
                ReportPropertyChanged("<#=primitiveProperty.Name#>");
                <#=ChangedMethodName(primitiveProperty)#>();
            }
```

Hope that will be helpfull to others.